# Assistance with SQL Query (aggregating)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to create a Sales report and I have a sql query:

```
SELECT  --top 1
                    t.branch_no as TBranchNo,
                    t.workstation_no as TWorkstation,
                    t.tender_ref_no as TSaleRefNo, 
                    t.tender_line_no as TLineNo, 
                    t.tender_code as TCode, 
                    T.contribution as TContribution, 
                    l.sale_line_no as SaleLineNo                    
            FROM TENDER_LINES t
            LEFT JOIN SALES_TX_LINES l 
                    on t.branch_no = l.branch_no and t.workstation_no = l.workstation_no and t.tender_ref_no = l.sale_tx_no
            where l.sale_tx_no = 2000293 OR l.sale_tx_no = 1005246 --OR sale_tx_no = 1005261
            order by t.tender_ref_no asc,
                     l.sale_line_no desc
```

The results of the query look like the following:
[image]

The results I am trying to achieve is:
[image: Result expected]

With only 1 line for transaction 2 either SaleLineNo 1 or 2, while still have=ing both lines for transaction 1 because the TCode is different.

Thanks

I am using SSQL2012.

Comment: I would appreciate if I know the reason for down voting. That gives  me a chance to not to make that mistake again.

Comment: Based on your data it seems that adding a simple AND SaleLineNo = 1 on your WHERE clause, would do the trick ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate your assistance with my query. After playing around, I have found a solution that works just as I want. It is as below: I did a Group by as hinted by @Yogesh86 on a few fields.

```
            SELECT 
                    MAX(t.branch_no) as TBranchNo,
                    Max(t.workstation_no) as TWorkstation,
                    t.tender_ref_no as TSaleRefNo, 
                    Max(t.tender_line_no) as TLineNo, 
                    t.tender_code as TCode, 
                    MAx(T.contribution) as TContribution, 
                    MAX(l.sale_line_no) as SaleLineNo                   
            FROM TENDER_LINES t
            LEFT JOIN SALES_TX_LINES l 
                    on t.branch_no = l.branch_no and t.workstation_no = l.workstation_no and t.tender_ref_no = l.sale_tx_no
                    where l.sale_tx_no = 2000293 OR l.sale_tx_no = 1005246 --OR sale_tx_no = 1005261
            GROUP BY 
                    t.tender_ref_no,
                    t.tender_line_no,
                    t.tender_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure on what data you have, but you might want to try

```
GROUP BY TlineNo, TCode ...
```

But you have to keep a look on not to group by something that would result in duplicate contribution values.

Comment: yes you have to but a group by but with combination of having clause meniton or in having condition  :)

Comment: I didnt have to use Having clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function that allows to partition the rows in groups, and number the lines inside each group starting by one. If you choose the right columns to define the partition, and keep only the rows with "row_number = 1`, you have solved the first part of your problem, i.e. discarding the lines that don't have to appear in the report. (See the sample sin the linked documentation, they're quite clear).

Once you have solved this problem, you simply have to repeat what you're doing, but on the result of this data, instead of the original data. You can use a view, [a CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), or a subselect to achieve your result, i.e.

With view:

```
CREATE VIEW FilteredData AS -- here the rank function query, then selct from the view

SELECT --here your current query -- 
FROM FilteredData
```

With [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
WITH -- here the rank function query
SELECT -- your current querym, from the CTE
```

With subselect

```
SELECT -- your current query
FROM (SELECT FROM -- here the rank function query -- )
```

Comment: Thanks for assistance @JotaBe. I figured out another way to get the results.